# SCORM 1.2 Nested Items In Manifest

Tags: manifest, scorm1.2

I've been trying to create a SCORM 1.2 manifest file that will create multiple SCOs with sub-files but, although there's plenty written about it online, I've been unable to find any actual examples. Essentially, what I want to do is:

- SCO1.html
  - SCO1.1.html
  - SCO1.2.html
  - SCO1.3.html

- SCO2.html
  - SCO2.1.html
  - SCO2.2.html
  - SCO2.3.html

In the above scenario, if the user was to launch SCO1.2.html, for example, their progress would be recorded against SCO1. I've got the following in my `imsmanifest.xml` file, but don't know how to restructure it so that each item is not a separate SCO. I've left out the metadata and resources that don't affect this issue:

```
<organizations default="TOC1">
<organization identifier="TOC1">
<title>Test</title >

<item identifier="I_SCO1" identifierref="SCO1">
<title>SCO1</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO1.1" identifierref="SCO1.1">
<title>SCO1.1</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO1.2" identifierref="SCO1.2">
<title>SCO1.2</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO1.3" identifierref="SCO1.3">
<title>SCO1.3</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO2" identifierref="SCO2">
<title>SCO2</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO2.1" identifierref="SCO2.1">
<title>SCO2.1</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO2.2" identifierref="SCO2.2">
<title>SCO2.2</title>
</item>
<item identifier="I_SCO2.3" identifierref="SCO2.3">
<title>SCO2.3</title>
</item>
</organization>
</organizations>

<resources>
<resource identifier="SCO1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO1.html">
<file href="SCO1.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO1.1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO1.1.html">
<file href="SCO1.1.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO1.2" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO1.2.html">
<file href="SCO1.2.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO1.3" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO1.3.html">
<file href="SCO1.3.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO2" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO2.html">
<file href="SCO2.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO2.1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO2.1.html">
<file href="SCO2.1.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO2.2" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO2.2.html">
<file href="SCO2.2.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
<resource identifier="SCO2.3" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="SCO2.3.html">
<file href="SCO2.3.html" />
<dependency identifierref="ALLRESOURCES" />
</resource>
</resources>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be looking at something a little closer to this-

```
 <organizations default="ORG-001">
<organization identifier="ORG-001">
  <title>Page Progression Sample</title>
  <item>
    <title>Module 1</title>
    <item identifier="ACT-001" identifierref="RES-001">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-002" identifierref="RES-002">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-003" identifierref="RES-003">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-004" identifierref="RES-004">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 2</title>
    <item identifier="ACT-005" identifierref="RES-005">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-006" identifierref="RES-006">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-007" identifierref="RES-007">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
    <item identifier="ACT-008" identifierref="RES-008">
        <title>Name of this page</title>
    </item>
  </item>
</organization>
```

But you could try nesting 2, 3, 4 within 1 to see if that works.  I don't have the specification in front of me right now.

In your example -

```
<item identifier="I_SCO1" identifierref="SCO1">
    <title>SCO1</title>
    <!-- PUT YOUR NEXT SCO (page) HERE-->
</item> <!-- Close tag of SCO1 -->
```